# Gradient across column of QPushButtons

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qpushbutton

I have a column of 4 QPushButtons which change their background colour when they are selected. They should all be the same colour - The stylesheet code is the same for the each of them;

```
ui->button1->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: rgb(225, 255, 200); }");
ui->button2->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: rgb(225, 255, 200); }");
ui->button3->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: rgb(225, 255, 200); }");
ui->button4->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background: rgb(225, 255, 200); }");
```

However, in practice the buttons seem to colour in a gradient from lighter to darker downwards in the column.

Does anyone know why this is so?

Comment: Have you actually sampled the colours (e.g. in an image editor such as GIMP)?  It's likely that you are seeing an optical illusion caused by change in background, or perhaps an artefact of your display hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions,  though it's certainly not an optical illusion, nor anything wrong with the monitor :/